# Java | JPA | Hibernate | AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, one-to-many

I'm getting my feet wet with Java Spring Boot 2.7.15 and I'm having a bit of trouble. I've applied several solutions but they all lead back to the same error in the title.

Some background:
I'm building a pet project learning management application where instructors have social media contact links. For this, I'm attempting to use a OneToMany relationship for Instructors to Socials.

Here's my code:

**InstructorEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"}))
public class InstructorEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String uuid;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String profession;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "longtext", length = 65555)
    private String bio;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String website;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "instructor_social",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "instructor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "instructor_social_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private List<InstructorSocial> socials = new ArrayList<>();

    public InstructorEntity() {
    }

    public InstructorEntity(long id, String uuid, String firstName, String lastName, String profession, String bio, String email, String phone, String website) {
        this.id = id;
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.bio = bio;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.website = website;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**InstructorSocialEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor_social")
public class InstructorSocialEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String uuid;
    private String name;
    private String image;

    public InstructorSocialEntity() {
    }

    public InstructorSocialEntity(long id, String uuid, String name, String image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Updated Working Code**

**Instructor.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"}))
public class Instructor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String uuid;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String profession;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "longtext", length = 65555)
    private String bio;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String website;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "instructor",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<InstructorSocial> socials = new ArrayList<>();

    public Instructor() {
    }

    public Instructor(long id, String uuid, String firstName, String lastName, String profession, String bio, String email, String phone, String website) {
        this.id = id;
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.bio = bio;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.website = website;
    }
```

**InstructorSocial.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor_social")
public class InstructorSocial {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String uuid;
    private String name;
    private String image;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_id")
    private Instructor instructor;

    public InstructorSocial() {
    }

    public InstructorSocial(long id, String uuid, String name, String image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }
```

---

**Edit**
Per one of the comments, I'm able to successfully run the app, but now I'm having a problem adding a Social to a list of the Instructor's Socials (i.e. Instructor.socials). The following code does, however, add the Social record into the instructor_social table in my database. Here's my code:

**InstructorService.java**

```
InstructorSocial social = new InstructorSocial();
social.setUuid();
social.setName(instructorSocial.getName());
social.setImage(instructorSocial.getImage());

foundInstructor.getSocials().add(social);
instructorRepository.save(foundInstructor);
```

**Solution to the edit**
For full transparency, I figured out why my Instructor.socials lists weren't being populated... It was because of my Instructor.socials Model. Long story short, it had everything to do with me not setting up my Service without even defining what the InstructerService.getAllInstructors() method should return. Here is what I used:

**service/InstructorServiceImpl.java**

```
@Override
    public List<Instructor> getAllInstructors() {
        return instructorRepository
                .findAll().stream()
                .map(instructorEntity -> new Instructor(
                        instructorEntity.getId(),
                        instructorEntity.getUuid(),
                        instructorEntity.getFirstName(),
                        instructorEntity.getLastName(),
                        instructorEntity.getProfession(),
                        instructorEntity.getBio(),
                        instructorEntity.getEmail(),
                        instructorEntity.getPhone(),
                        instructorEntity.getWebsite(),
                        instructorEntity.getSocials()
                                .stream()
                                .map(instructorSocialEntity -> new InstructorSocial(
                                        instructorSocialEntity.getId(),
                                        instructorSocialEntity.getUuid(),
                                        instructorSocialEntity.getName(),
                                        instructorSocialEntity.getImage()
                                ))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                ))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations like `@JoinTable` ,`@JoinColumn` are applied to the owning side of
a relationship, i.e. the table that owns the foreign key to the other table.

Here, have a look at the [javadocs of the annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html).

In the relationship between your tables, the owning side is the `instructor_social` table, so, it is the one that should have the `@JoinXXX` annotation on the field that represents the related table/Entity, i.e. instructor/InstructorEntity.

Another thing that is missing in your code, that the Hibernate(JPA) complains of, is that the lack of `mappedBy` attribute in your `@OneToMany` annotation.

Again, as per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html),

> If the relationship is bidirectional, the mappedBy element must be used to specify the relationship field or property of the entity that is the owner of the relationship.

Meaning, you have to update your `@OneToMany` annotation like so:

```
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "instructor",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<InstructorSocial> socials = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here, `mappedBy` indicates how this entity (Instructor) is referenced from the owning entity (InstructorSocial).

That means, you have to update your InstructorSocial entity to include the reference to the Instructor entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "instructor_id")
private InstructorEntity instructor;
```

Notice the **field name** in the owning entity is the same as the value of the `mappedBy` attribute in the referenced entity, i.e "instructor". That specifies the bidirectional relation of these two entities.

---

As a side note, you might consider refining the naming of your entities. Appending them with the suffix 'xxxEntity' can appear overly explanatory and may not enhance readability when sorted. Plus, Hibernate has the ability of generating the table and relation names from entities and their mapping configurations by the widely accepted RDBMS naming conventions. By allowing Hibernate to handle table organization, you can effectively address many trivial issues that may arise, especially if you are new to this field.

Comment: So I have a question. This worked as you've typed it and I was able to run by app, but now when I try to save InstructorSocial to my Instructor, it doesn't show up in my list of Instructor.socials list, but it DOES show up in the database. What am I doing wrong?


`InstructorSocial social = new InstructorSocial();
social.setUuid();
social.setName(instructorSocial.getName());
social.setImage(instructorSocial.getImage());
social.setInstructor(foundInstructor);

foundInstructor.getSocials().add(social);
instructorRepository.save(foundInstructor);`

Comment: It is best to enable debug level on the generated hibernate SQL queries to see what's going on behind the scenes. Just look up how to set `hibernate.show_sql` flag to true in the environment you're doing the development.

Comment: Already had it set when I first started on the app. There's only a mention of the INSERT INTO instructor_social table.

`Hibernate: insert into instructor_social (image, instructor_uuid, name, uuid) values (?, ?, ?, ?)`

All the data in that table is getting set, but the record isn't being added into the instructor's list of socials using the .add() method

Comment: That is weird. Have you replaced your `@JoinTable` annotation with `@JoinColumn` as I showed in the example ? Because your configuration implies a many-to-many relation where two columns of this table being `instructor_id` and `instructor_social_id` which both referencing the `id` column in their respective tables. This is not what you want. You only need a column in the owning table (instructor_social) that has a foreign key to the `instructor` table. Let's modify the code to satisfy that and retry.

Comment: Yup, did that already as well. I updated my original post to be more concise, plus I added a section underneath the title "Updated Working Code" that included all of your recommendations.

Comment: Never mind @alegria. I figured it out. Refer to my edited original post.

Comment: That's intersting, anyways, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

It complains the class that `@OneTomany` is annotated on which is `InstructorSocial` is not an entity. Entity is a class that is annotated with `@Entity`.

So think that it should be :

```java
@OneToMany(....)
@JoinTable(.....)
private List<InstructorSocialEntity > socials = new ArrayList<>();
```